# I want to calculate the due date for a pregnant woman after she inputs her date of pregnacy in php

Tags: php, html, datetime-format, calculation

I have pregdate as the date of pregnancy and duedate as the due date for the pregnancy. But when I run the code, I get "Due Date: 1970-01-01" instead of the required 9 months added to the date of pregancy.
The trial date i used for one of the patients is 2020-01-01 so I should get 2020-10-01

```
$duedate = strtotime("+9 months", strtotime($pregdate));
$duedate = strftime ( '%Y-%m-%d' , $pregdate );
echo $duedate;
```

Comment: Use [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) for dates, almost everything else is just...bad...

Comment: should be `$duedate = strftime ( '%Y-%m-%d' , $duedate );` wrong variable assignment

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding 40 weeks?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.
The problem is that you have two strtotime, and as mentioned in comments wrong variable.

```
$pregdate = '2020-01-01';
$duedate = strtotime($pregdate . " +9 months");
$duedate = strftime ( '%Y-%m-%d' , $duedate );
echo $duedate;
```

Strtotime can only get string as input so when you have two nested as you did, one gets a string the second gets a integer (the output of strtotime is integer) and it can't handle that so it fails and returns false which is also 0.
The date of zero is 1970-01-01.
That is why you get that output.